# My citizens are too smart

Tags: cities-skylines

Specialized industries (forestry, mining, etc) require relatively uneducated workers.  Unfortunately, I placed a strong emphasis on education in my city, and over half the population (including children) have university degrees.  Not really suitable for doing grunt work.

So if my education system is so top notch, how do I attract the uneducated folk to my fine city so that they can work the mines?

Comment: Maybe if you built new residential zones which are outside the reach of any school?

Comment: Why do you care? With such an educated population, you shouldn't need industry at all. It's a great boost when starting a new village near some resources (outside of the reach of your education), but eventually you can just switch to commerce and offices.

Comment: this question made me chuckle!  Make sure you set up a separate bus system so your refined folk don't have to see the poor :D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you are under the assumption that Highly Educated Workers cannot work the Uneducated jobs.

[image: Over Educated]

They indeed will *eventually* fill whatever jobs are available. At first they may not want to go work there, and the dirty industries may complain when they first go into business that there are no workers, but the Highly Educated will eventually go work there. The industry itself will display that they are "overeducated" — which doesn't appear to impact its performance any. So feel free to send those university degree children to the mines :D

Of course, theoretically if they went to work these lower jobs and you had some Highly Educated positions somewhere else, they wouldn't be available for those jobs. But then again you have no real way to control of who-works-where anyway.

Comment: Part of the problem I'm seeing is that no matter how long I leave them, the buildings always have the "need more workers" icon.  When I switch the district back to generic industry, I don't see the icon, and the industry flourishes.

Comment: Try looking around on the subreddit for more info. I found this thread, for instance: http://www.reddit.com/r/CitiesSkylines/comments/2z1kmv/industry_can_employ_educated_citizens_it_just/

Comment: and here: http://www.reddit.com/r/CitiesSkylines/comments/2ywwuw/district_specializations_and_education/

Comment: Games resemble real life more and more day by day...

Comment: Are you sure there's no 'job satisfaction' factor in happiness?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to operate these industries fine with educated workers. Have some residential zone laid down out of range of any education facilities, but within the range of the industries you want them to staff.

You can use the view modes in the top right (or by selecting the education panel) to see how far your education reaches your city, your residential buildings should be red if they're out of range.

Comment: Does it need to be low density residential? Wouldn't high density pack more uneducated workers into a small space?

Comment: Maybe not, actually. I'd got the text confused with the one for offices, which specifies that it requires educated workers

Comment: Also, I tried this method, but somehow the buildings in my "uneducated" zone were populated with about 40% uneducated, and the other 60 evenly distributed amongst the education levels.

Answer (score 1):

Just separate your industrial zone from everything else and then put houses a stones throw from it! Then make sure that education is very far away from them.

Answer (score 0):

Level 3 industrial requires more educated workers than level 1 industrial (the building will show the breakdown required when selected). Be sure to add cargo trains and public transit to help it level up, as well as other services.

For specialized industries I'm not sure how it differs.